# XCode: Unable to download crash information

Tags: xcode, testflight, crash-reports

I have an app in testflight, and am trying to look at the Crash information.
I went to the Organizer, clicked on Crashes, chose the version, and clicked load. It spun for a while then came back with an error:

Error Downloading Crashes List
An error occurred preventing Xcode from downloading crashes list. my@email.com failed with error: Waiting for future 'CrashPointNetworkListSource' to complete timed out.

I am using Xcode 14.3

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

I tried various permutations of the options at the top (e.g. all versions vs. a specific version).

Comment: Is your AppStoreConnect account in good standing / have you accepted the Program License Agreement? I know you asked this question a while ago but I'm running into the same issue and after accepting the agreement, I'm getting a different error. Apple hasn't yet approved the agreement but I'll update once they do.